# How to implement PK battle (like the one in likee app) using Agora?

Tags: java, android, webrtc, video-streaming, agora

I am broadcasting my live and join others channel fine. However I am looking forward to implement PK battle in my app. How do I broadcast live and join someone's channel at the same time?

I tried to create 2 RtcEngine, But it seems to be static so I can create only one instance.

What I am trying to do is Broadcast my live and Broadcast my friends live we both join each others channel and show both streams to other people at the same time? This sounds crazy but this is the only idea I have right now. Is there any other way? If not how do I implement this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.